# Filling a select box with certain array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a form and I need to fill in the options of a select box named county (from an array) based on what the user selects from the select box named country (eg the user selects GB in the country box and the county box populates with options for all the GB counties in the array).
The code I have fills in the select box, but puts an option in for every value in the array (an empty one for where the values do not match and a filled in one for where they do match. This is a big problem because I have over 4000 items in my array, yet only want to return a few results. Here is are the first 50 items in the array:

```
ISO_3316_2[0][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[0][1] = "AF-BDS";
ISO_3316_2[0][2] = "Badakhshan";
ISO_3316_2[1][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[1][1] = "AF-BDG";
ISO_3316_2[1][2] = "Badghis";
ISO_3316_2[2][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[2][1] = "AF-BGL";
ISO_3316_2[2][2] = "Baghlan";
ISO_3316_2[3][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[3][1] = "AF-BAL";
ISO_3316_2[3][2] = "Balkh";
ISO_3316_2[4][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[4][1] = "AF-BAM";
ISO_3316_2[4][2] = "Bamian";
ISO_3316_2[5][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[5][1] = "AF-DAY";
ISO_3316_2[5][2] = "Daykondi";
ISO_3316_2[6][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[6][1] = "AF-FRA";
ISO_3316_2[6][2] = "Farah";
ISO_3316_2[7][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[7][1] = "AF-FYB";
ISO_3316_2[7][2] = "Faryab";
ISO_3316_2[8][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[8][1] = "AF-GHA";
ISO_3316_2[8][2] = "Ghazni";
ISO_3316_2[9][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[9][1] = "AF-GHO";
ISO_3316_2[9][2] = "Ghowr";
ISO_3316_2[10][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[10][1] = "AF-HEL";
ISO_3316_2[10][2] = "Helmand";
ISO_3316_2[11][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[11][1] = "AF-HER";
ISO_3316_2[11][2] = "Herat";
ISO_3316_2[12][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[12][1] = "AF-JOW";
ISO_3316_2[12][2] = "Jowzjan";
ISO_3316_2[13][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[13][1] = "AF-KAB";
ISO_3316_2[13][2] = "Kabul [Kabol]";
ISO_3316_2[14][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[14][1] = "AF-KAN";
ISO_3316_2[14][2] = "Kandahar";
ISO_3316_2[15][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[15][1] = "AF-KAP";
ISO_3316_2[15][2] = "Kapisa";
ISO_3316_2[16][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[16][1] = "AF-KHO";
ISO_3316_2[16][2] = "Khowst";
ISO_3316_2[17][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[17][1] = "AF-KNR";
ISO_3316_2[17][2] = "Konar [Kunar]";
ISO_3316_2[18][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[18][1] = "AF-KDZ";
ISO_3316_2[18][2] = "Kondoz [Kunduz]";
ISO_3316_2[19][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[19][1] = "AF-LAG";
ISO_3316_2[19][2] = "Laghman";
ISO_3316_2[20][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[20][1] = "AF-LOW";
ISO_3316_2[20][2] = "Lowgar";
ISO_3316_2[21][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[21][1] = "AF-NAN";
ISO_3316_2[21][2] = "Nangrahar [Nangarhar]";
ISO_3316_2[22][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[22][1] = "AF-NIM";
ISO_3316_2[22][2] = "Nimruz";
ISO_3316_2[23][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[23][1] = "AF-NUR";
ISO_3316_2[23][2] = "Nurestan";
ISO_3316_2[24][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[24][1] = "AF-ORU";
ISO_3316_2[24][2] = "Oruzgan [Uruzgan]";
ISO_3316_2[25][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[25][1] = "AF-PIA";
ISO_3316_2[25][2] = "Paktia";
ISO_3316_2[26][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[26][1] = "AF-PKA";
ISO_3316_2[26][2] = "Paktika";
ISO_3316_2[27][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[27][1] = "AF-PAN";
ISO_3316_2[27][2] = "Panjshir";
ISO_3316_2[28][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[28][1] = "AF-PAR";
ISO_3316_2[28][2] = "Parwan";
ISO_3316_2[29][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[29][1] = "AF-SAM";
ISO_3316_2[29][2] = "Samangan";
ISO_3316_2[30][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[30][1] = "AF-SAR";
ISO_3316_2[30][2] = "Sar-e Pol";
ISO_3316_2[31][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[31][1] = "AF-TAK";
ISO_3316_2[31][2] = "Takhar";
ISO_3316_2[32][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[32][1] = "AF-WAR";
ISO_3316_2[32][2] = "Wardak [Wardag]";
ISO_3316_2[33][0] = "AF";
ISO_3316_2[33][1] = "AF-ZAB";
ISO_3316_2[33][2] = "Zabol [Zabul]";
ISO_3316_2[34][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[34][1] = "AL-BR";
ISO_3316_2[34][2] = "Berat";
ISO_3316_2[35][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[35][1] = "AL-BU";
ISO_3316_2[35][2] = "Bulqiz";
ISO_3316_2[36][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[36][1] = "AL-DL";
ISO_3316_2[36][2] = "Delvin";
ISO_3316_2[37][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[37][1] = "AL-DV";
ISO_3316_2[37][2] = "Devoll";
ISO_3316_2[38][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[38][1] = "AL-DI";
ISO_3316_2[38][2] = "Dib";
ISO_3316_2[39][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[39][1] = "AL-DR";
ISO_3316_2[39][2] = "Durr";
ISO_3316_2[40][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[40][1] = "AL-EL";
ISO_3316_2[40][2] = "Elbasan";
ISO_3316_2[41][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[41][1] = "AL-FR";
ISO_3316_2[41][2] = "Fier";
ISO_3316_2[42][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[42][1] = "AL-GJ";
ISO_3316_2[42][2] = "Gjirokast";
ISO_3316_2[43][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[43][1] = "AL-GR";
ISO_3316_2[43][2] = "Gramsh";
ISO_3316_2[44][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[44][1] = "AL-HA";
ISO_3316_2[44][2] = "Has";
ISO_3316_2[45][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[45][1] = "AL-KA";
ISO_3316_2[45][2] = "Kavaj";
ISO_3316_2[46][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[46][1] = "AL-ER";
ISO_3316_2[46][2] = "Kolonj";
ISO_3316_2[47][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[47][1] = "AL-KO";
ISO_3316_2[47][2] = "Kor";
ISO_3316_2[48][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[48][1] = "AL-KR";
ISO_3316_2[48][2] = "Kruj";
ISO_3316_2[49][0] = "AL";
ISO_3316_2[49][1] = "AL-KU";
ISO_3316_2[49][2] = "Kuk";
```

And here is the javascript function:

```
function ISO3316CountyChange(country) {

    //Empty the options array
    document.test.county.options.length = 0;

    //For every item in the array
    for (i=0; i<ISO_3316_2.length; i++){

        //If the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value in the array matches the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value from the country select field
        if(ISO_3316_2[i][0] == country) {

            //Add an unselected option for the country with the ISO 3316-2 value as the value and the ISO 3316-2 name as the user visible value
            document.test.county.options[i]=new Option(ISO_3316_2[i][2], ISO_3316_2[i][1], false, false);

        };

    };

    //Add the default field
    document.test.county.options[i]=new Option("Please select a county/state", "", true, true); 
};
```

And here is the form:

```
<form name="test">

<select name="country" onChange="ISO3316CountyChange(this.value)">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select a country</option>
    <option value="AF">AF</option>
    <option value="GB">GB</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
</select>

<select name="county">
    <option value="">Please select a country first</option>
</select>
```

The easiest way to test this with the array snippet is to select the "AF" option, as this snippet contains entries for Afghanistan (AF) and Albania (AL).

**EDIT**

Thanks Max, that worked good apart from one amend :). Here is the new function:

//Change the counties in the counties select box
function ISO3316CountyChange(country) {

```
//Empty the options array
document.test.county.options.length = 0;

//Add the default field
document.test.county.options[0]=new Option("Please select a county/state", "", true, true);

//Variable containing the index of next option you should use
var nextOptionNum = 1;

//For every item in the array
for (i=0; i<ISO_3316_2.length; i++){

    //If the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value in the array matches the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value from the country select field
    if(ISO_3316_2[i][0] == country) {

        //Add an unselected option for the country with the ISO 3316-2 value as the value and the ISO 3316-2 name as the user visible value using the index of the next option
        document.test.county.options[nextOptionNum]=new Option(ISO_3316_2[i][2], ISO_3316_2[i][1], false, false);
        nextOptionNum++; //Increase the index ONLY if you used it
    };

};
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int nextOptionNum = 0; //Variable containing the index of next option you should use
//For every item in the array
for (i=0; i<ISO_3316_2.length; i++){

    //If the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value in the array matches the ISO 3316 alpha 2 value from the country select field
    if(ISO_3316_2[i][0] == country) {

        //Add an unselected option for the country with the ISO 3316-2 value as the value and the ISO 3316-2 name as the user visible value
        //Use the index of the next option
        document.test.county.options[nextOptionNum]=new Option(ISO_3316_2[i][2], ISO_3316_2[i][1], false, false);
        nextOptionNum++; //Increase the index ONLY if you used it
    };
};
```

Comment: Then could you press the big green button near my answer? Thanks :)